# What are the effects of disabling scripting in a JSP?

Tags: jsp

I recently read how to disable scripting for an entire application by adding the following elements to the web.xml file:

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

It went on to state that doing this forces you to always use standard JSP tags, EL, and JSTL instead of scripting, but it doesn't define 'scripting'. I was under the impression that EL is a form of scripting, and now I'm left wondering what is it I can't do exactly, after I disable scripting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It disables [*scriptlets*](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html) (`<% %>`), [*scriptlet expressions*](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaov.html) (`<%= %>`) and [*scriptlet declarations*](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaos.html) (`<%! %>`), which is a way of embedding raw Java code inside a JSP file. Using *scriptlets* has indeed been [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) since the birth of taglibs/EL in favor of better readable and maintainable code.

#### See also:

- [Java EE 5 tutorial - disabling scripting](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaoq.html)

Comment: It only disables scriptlets? What about the other JSP tags? Does it disable expressions, directives, comments, and declarations?

Comment: Scriptlets, expressions and declarations. Not directives and comments. I updated the answer.

Comment: Ah, the idea of "embedding raw Java code inside a JSP file" makes perfect sense and answers my question. Thx

Answer (score 2):

It disables scriptlets, which is basically java code in the JSP e.g.

<% request.getAttribute("bob"); %>

would not be allowed.

JSTL, EL, etc. will all work fine.